control wowza next segment https scheme

We have a wowza server in a google-cloud run docker container.
The cloud run docker container has a Load balancer that accepts https
connections then terminates TLS, then contacts the wowza server on
our http HostPort.
When wowza responds with the next segment request it formulates an
http request for the next segment.
Since the load balancer does not accept http requests the stream
playback does not continue.
We are using an embedded shaka player and WOWZA mpegdashstreaming.

My question is there a mechanism to control the URL scheme
(http/https) even though a HostPort contacted was not configured
with <SSLConfig>? I want the next segment URL to use the https
scheme.
I would like to be able to control the next segment request URL scheme.
I tried finding a setting for the cloud-run container load balancer to continue https to wowza.
I tried finding wowza documentation setting that might change the behavior.
